# Convergence of a level set when $f^n\to f$ in $C^1$ sense

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $f^n$ be a family of $C^1$ functions and $f(x)=-|x|^2+1$ such that
$$f^n\to f$$
in $C^1$ sense as $\varepsilon\to 0$. I want to ask that does the level set $\{f^n=0\}$ converges to $\{f=0\}$ in some sense as $\varepsilon\to 0$? Is $\{f^n=0\}$ still a $C^1$ curve for $\varepsilon $ sufficiently small?

Comment: A nice trick is, if you search for the level set $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ for some $c$, you can alternatively study $|f-c|^2$ and ask for its minima.

Comment: @nicrot000 but this destroys the regularity of the 0 level set of f, which is the main and general reason why both facts are true . For the set of minima the analog results are not true, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta$Apparently, (i) by $\epsilon\to0$ you meant $n\to\infty$ and (ii) by "$f^n\to f$ in $C^1$ sense" you meant that
$$\sup_x|f^n(x)-f(x)|+\sup_x|\nabla f^n(x)-\nabla f(x)|\to0. \tag{1}$$
If so, then the answers to both of your questions are positive:

> Question 1: "does the level set $\{f^n=0\}$ converges to $\{f=0\}$ in some sense as $\varepsilon\to 0$?"

Answer 1: Take any $\de\in(0,1]$. If $|x|\le1-\de$, then $f(x)=1-|x|^2\ge1-(1-\de)^2\ge\de$. So, by (1), eventually (that is, for all large enough $n$) $f^n(x)>0$ for all $x$ with $|x|\le1-\de$. Similarly, if $|x|\ge1+\de$, then $f(x)=1-|x|^2\le1-(1+\de)^2\le-2\de$. So, eventually $f^n(x)<0$ for all $x$ with $|x|\ge1+\de$. So, eventually the set $\{f^n=0\}$ will be $\de$-close to the set $\{f=0\}=\{x\colon|x|=1\}$.

> Question 2: "Is $\{f^n=0\}$ still a $C^1$ curve for $\varepsilon $ sufficiently small?"

Answer 2: The gradient $\nabla f(x)=-2x$ is bounded away from $0$ for all $x$ in a small enough open neighborhood, say $U$, of the set $\{f=0\}$. So, by (1), eventually the gradient $\nabla f^n$ will be bounded away from $0$ in $U$. Moreover, by Answer 1, eventually the set $\{f^n=0\}$ will be contained in $U$. So, eventually the gradient $\nabla f^n$ will be bounded away from $0$ in an open neighborhood of the set $\{f^n=0\}$. So, eventually $\{f^n=0\}$ will be a $C^1$ curve, by the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)